# How to implement REST Pagination using offset in mapping data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

When using REST as a source for a mapping data flow, documentation indicates that RANGE-based pagination is not supported. When using a copy activity with ranged pagination, it supports REST APIs that use an offset paging strategy as shown below and would calculate the next offset value by adding 1000 to the existing offset in the body.

```
baseUrl/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1000&sysparm_offset=0,
baseUrl/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1000&sysparm_offset=1000,
...... 
baseUrl/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1000&sysparm_offset=10000
```

In data flows, I don't see how to add some value to the existing offset in the body for the next REST call. I can certainly get to the current offset value in the header or body, but how would I add 1000 to it? When not using dynamic content, I can't seem to leverage a function to add to the offset value in the body.  If I use dynamic content, I don't seem to have access to the JSON node @odata.offset.  What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the **Filter activity** we can generate all numbers in our range using `range()` function and then the Filter condition with `mod` to get numbers divisible by 1000, ie

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Items | @range(1,11000) |
| Condition | @equals(mod(item(),1000),0) |

You will get the array with required numbers to be set for offset.

[image]
2. Now pass this array to foreach activity as below
[image]
3. Create parameter with type string in source Rest DataSource.
[image]

4. Pass that parameter as Dynamic value in relative URL. your values are as follows:

```
base Url: baseUrl/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1000&
realtive Url: sysparm_offset=@{dataset().offset}
```

[image]

5. After this gave parameter value as  `@item()`  to give the no coming from range to the page.

[image]